# MYSQL Procedure call saved query in table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

That I need is

1. Save all of query in one table

   ```
   query_id | sql_query
   1        | select * from ms_user
   2        | select * from ms_privileges
   ```
2. Create Procedure
   this procedure will call

   ```
   call my_procedure(query_id)
   ```

I tried the code below

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mp_test; 
CREATE PROCEDURE global_procedire(IN id_query int(10));
BEGIN 
  SET @Query = 'SELECT sql_query from ms_query where query_id = id_query';
  SET @Query = CONCAT(@Query);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @Query; 
  EXECUTE stmt; 
END
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried/done so far.

Comment: thanks for adding code! But you added the info as an answer, can you edit your question, and include that info there? You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link just below the tags of your question.

Comment: Are you trying to create a stored procedure that logs all SQL statements that are executed on your DB?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I improved the code formatting a bit.  I also indented your code sample by 4 or 8 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting.